# Simplifying click and toggle function in jquery

Tags: jquery, hide, toggle, show

Ok well I need some help because I am plain stuck. I am trying to make a simple drop down type menu which will be used for a different purpose then a navigation menu. But anyway I can get it to work perfectly, I just need some help simplyfing the code. Here is the html:

```
<div class="big">
    <a href="#" id="atog1">Hello</a>
    <a href="#" id="atog2">Hello</a>
    <a href="#" >Hello</a>
    <a href="#">Hello</a>
<br clear="all">
    <div id="drop" class="atog1">This is a toggled div1!</div>
    <div id="drop" class="atog2">This is a toggled div2!</div>
</div>
```

Here is the Jquery initial code that works beautifully but I am going to need to have up to 20 different a and divs to show and I do not want all that code. So I am trying to put it in a clean simple short snippet of code:

```
//Make the toggled div
$('#atog1').show();
$('div.atog1').hide();
$('#atog1').click(function(){
    $('div.atog2').hide();
    $('div.atog1').slideToggle();
});
//Make the toggled div2
$('div.atog2').hide();
$('#atog2').click(function(){
    $('div.atog1').hide();
    $('div.atog2').slideToggle();   
});
```

And here is where I got stuck, This is what is supposed to be a shorter version of the above, but when I click on the first a it opens div and when I click on the second a it hides first div but then if I click on the first a again it does not hide div:

```
$('div[class^=atog]').hide();

$('a').click(function(){
    var tid = $(this).attr('id');
    $('div#drop[class!='+tid+']').hide();
    $('div#drop[class='+tid+']').slideToggle();
});
```

I know there should be a really simple solution, but I can just not see it. Thanks to anyone in advance and here is my jsfiddle if that is more helpful! 
http://jsfiddle.net/liveandream/stGF9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple elements with the same `id`.

You should use classes when they need to be shared.  Here is one example of how you could change it.

http://jsfiddle.net/stGF9/54/

```
$('div.drop').hide();

$('a').click(function(){
    var tid = $(this).attr('id');
    var el = $('div.drop.'+tid);

    $('div.drop').not(el).hide();
    el.slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Not to be picky, but you could make it a little shorter by using var tid = this.id; instead of using .attr('id')...  every byte counts ;)

Comment: Yeah, it's slightly better that way, but it wasn't the part breaking it so I left it unchanged.

Comment: Thank you so much James.. I knew it was something super simple that I just was not seeing! This worked perfectly!